# redux toolkit selected return status "uninitialized"

Tags: redux, store, redux-toolkit

Use toolkit adapter and create api which will return auto generated hooks.

Tried to use the hook with some parameter it cause the selected **status** "**uninitialized**".

**Updated:**

Check from the redux store there, i saw the issue that cause cannot retrieve the value as ecpected.

**export const selectUsersResult = usersApiSlice.endpoints.getUsers.select()**
That is because the select() empty, so it not any value in the redux store.

As example to use that:
In UserList Component
const { data } = useGetUsersQuery("page=1&limit=10");

In the slice
export const selectUsersResult = usersApiSlice.endpoints.getUsers.select("page=1&limit=10");

that is my understanding, and facing other issue. How can i update the select() according with the state change.

**End Updated**

**Original Issue:**

```
const usersAdapter = createEntityAdapter({})

export const initialState = usersAdapter.getInitialState()

export const usersApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: (args) => {
        console.log("args: ", args)

        return {
          url: `/api/users/`,
          method: "GET",
          params: { page: 1, limit: 10 },
        }
      },
      validateStatus: (response, result) => {
        return response.status === 200 && !result.isError
      },
      transformResponse: (responseData) => {
        console.log("responseData...", responseData)

        const loadedUsers = responseData?.users.map((user) => user)

        return usersAdapter.setAll(initialState, loadedUsers)
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
        if (result?.ids) {
          return [
            { type: "User", id: "LIST" },
            ...result.ids.map((id) => ({ type: "User", id })),
          ]
        } else return [{ type: "User", id: "LIST" }]
      },
    }),
})

// auto generated hook
export const { useGetUsersQuery } = usersApiSlice

export const selectUsersResult = usersApiSlice.endpoints.getUsers.select()

// creates memoized selector
const selectUsersData = createSelector(selectUsersResult, (usersResult) => {
  console.log("usersResult. ", usersResult) <<------- return status uninitialized without data object here

  return usersResult.data
})

export const {
  selectById: selectUserById, 
} = usersAdapter.getSelectors((state) => selectUsersData(state) ?? initialState)
```

Listing **two way** below to use the hook with **params** or **undefined**

```
const UserList = () => {
  const { data } = useGetUsersQuery({page: 1, limit: 10}) // <---- status uninitialized without data object in usersResult 

 
  const { data } = useGetUsersQuery(undefined) // <---- status fulfilled with expected data object in usersResult


  return <div>user table</div>
}
```

selectUserById from selected method cannot retrieve the data